# JavaScript - Zip Code gets converted to a number

Tags: javascript

I have five digit US zip codes coming out of the database. When JavaScript see them, it treats them as a number and lops off the leading zeros.

How do I get JavaScript to treat the numbers as a string so that they display correctly?

Comment: Strings are strings until you write code to convert them to numbers. Seriously.

Comment: _When JavaScript see them_: How? You have to show us how you are "sending the numbers from the database to javascript"

Comment: Just add `+''` right after the zip code..

Comment: are you trying to validate that the user specified a correct zip code format?

Comment: If you are sending them as JSON just do `{"zip":"000"}` instead of `{"zip":000}`.

Comment: @Prusse, your answer was exactly correct.  Thanks!

Comment: @Evik - That's why posting code helps to find coding errors ;-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote them.

In both JavaScript and JSON `05123` is an octal number equal to `2643` (thanks @Marc B) and `"05123"` is a string containing only numeric characters.

Don't quote them in your database, of course.  You'll want to quote them in the JavaScript or JSON you are generating in the server-side code that's reading the information from the database and passing it to your client-side code. Ordinarily, that's as simple as casting the zip code to a string (or, as is the more likely case, **not** casting your numeric zips to a number.)

Comment: Actually, no. 05123 is an octal number, equalling 2643 decimal. Try `alert(05123)` sometime.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function which pads a number until it's 5 characters long.

```
function formatzip(num) {
    var s = "00000"+num;
    return s.substr(s.length-5);
}
```

But really the zip code should never have turned into a number in the first place. It should be a string when you set it's value to begin with.

Comment: Nice, this is a whole lot cleaner than mine, real neat :)

Comment: While this is a pretty elegant snippet, it solves a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: I actually integrated this solution into the database to ensure that anything coming out of the database would be five digits.  Yes, this solves a problem that may not exist, but it's a nice part of the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that `String()` would probably work. If by that time, the 0s are already lopped off, you could do something like:

```
zip = <Source>;
zip = String(zip);
while(zip.length<5){
  zip = "0" + zip;
}
```

Tell me if this isn't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A guess... Some genius decided to store ZIP codes in a numeric column type inside the database (`NUMBER`, `INT` or whatever type your DBMS implements). If that was the case, all ZIP codes that start with zero are already corrupted.

It'd be better to switch the column to `VARCHAR` before it's too late and fix the corrupted rows manually.